# Implement Custom Logger with slf4j

Tags: java, slf4j

I want to implement a Custom logger which logs all log entries to a Database.
Currently my app logs this way (slf4j and log4j binding):

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( MyClass.class );
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.
My Idea is to implement a Custom Logging binding 
through implementing the [org.slf4j.Logger Interface](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html)

What would be the next steps? 
My target is to not change the current code

Links I considered:

- [Java custom logger: logging standards or/and best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770442/java-custom-logger-logging-standards-or-and-best-practices)
- http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html

Comment: Logback (http://logback.qos.ch) - native SLF4J implementation can log to database.

Comment: @Bruno Reis, Yes. Logback natively implements the SLF4J API.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/custom-logback-appender .

Answer (score 39, accepted):

it should be fairly easy. you'll need to implement your own `Logger` and `LoggerFactory`. you will not have to change existing code at all.

after doing that you'll need to implement `StaticLoggerBinder` to return your logger factory and class name. if you download the slf4j zip file then you get the source for all the implementations too, just have a look at the StaticLoggerBinder in slf4j-log4j for an example.

have a look at this link for details : http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#slf4j_compatible

Comment: Thanks oedo!
Is it also possible to use log4j in my logging framework, e.g. to only write errors and warning to the Database and use log4j for the rest?
The problem is that I have 2 bindings than http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings

Comment: at the moment it seems a custom log4j appender is what i'm looking for so warn error and warning level goes to my custom appender while the rest remains at it is (configured in log4j.xml)

Comment: sure, i guess you could write your custom logger so that it forwards the relevant requests to log4j. again, have a look at the source for slf4j-log4j to get you started :)

Comment: Seems like what I would be looking for, but for sure some code examples would have helped.

Answer (score 7):

You do not have to write your own logging implementation, how about switching the logging framework to [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)? Loback supports logging to database natively. As you use the SLF4J API both times your code won't change.

Take a look at the [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html). If the default table layout does not fit your needs, you can implement [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.names.DBNameResolver](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/db/names/package-tree.html) to customzie the table and coloum names.