# slf4j add custom method

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I have to add custom method method to my logging system. Let's say I have in several places line of code like: 
`private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJavaClass.class);`

Logging is handling by slf4j. How can I extend my logger with adding new(!) method like `public void error(SomeTypeObject obj) { /implementation/ }`

The goal is to not change existing code. How can I force LoggerFactory to return my own Logger implementation extended with mentioned method?

I followed answers for this queston: stackoverflow.com/questions/2653855/implement-custom-logger-with-slf4j

So, I've made my LoggerFactory, StaticLoggerBinder and MyLoggerAdapter.

**StaticLoggerBinder**

```
public class StaticLoggerBinder implements LoggerFactoryBinder {

    private static final StaticLoggerBinder SINGLETON = new StaticLoggerBinder();

    public static final StaticLoggerBinder getSingleton() {
        return SINGLETON;
    }

    public static String REQUESTED_API_VERSION = "1.6.99";

    private static final String loggerFactoryClassStr = MyLoggerFactory.class.getName();

    private final ILoggerFactory loggerFactory;

    private StaticLoggerBinder() {
        loggerFactory = new MyLoggerFactory();
    }

    public ILoggerFactory getLoggerFactory() {
        return loggerFactory;
    }

    public String getLoggerFactoryClassStr() {
        return loggerFactoryClassStr;
    }
}
```

**Logger Factory**

```
public class MyLoggerFactory implements ILoggerFactory {

    ConcurrentMap<String, Logger> loggerMap;

    public MyLoggerFactory() {
        loggerMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Logger>();
    }

    public Logger getLogger(String name) {
        Logger simpleLogger = loggerMap.get(name);
        if (simpleLogger != null) {
            return simpleLogger;
        } else {
            Logger newInstance = new MyLoggerAdapter(name);
            Logger oldInstance = loggerMap.putIfAbsent(name, newInstance);
            return oldInstance == null ? newInstance : oldInstance;
        }
    }

    void reset() {
        loggerMap.clear();
    }
}
```

**MyLogger**

```
public class MyLoggerAdapter implements Logger {
//methods from Logger interface
//and my additional method

    public void error(Exception ex) {
        //do smthng;
    }
}
```

Now, in MyJavaClass i have a field
`private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJavaClass.class);`

The problem is, when i try to `LOGGER.error(myExceptionObject)` the method is not visible. I am missing something. I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement Custom Logger with slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653855/implement-custom-logger-with-slf4j)

Answer (score 1):

In your `MyJavaClass` you should use your `MyLoggerFactory`:

```
private static MyLoggerAdapter LOGGER = MyLoggerFactory.getLogger();
```

instead of

```
private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJavaClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example logger can get so:

```
private static MyLoggerAdapter log = (MyLoggerAdapter) StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton().getLoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class.getName());
```