# How to ALSO send kotlin-logging logs (sl4j-simple?) to my own back-end

Tags: logging, kotlin, slf4j, kotlin-logging

I have a working solution using kotlin-logging and slf4j-simple.  It happily prints to the console.

Question: I'd like to **also** send log lines to my own function so I can save them to my alternate destination (that isn't one of the built-in ones like a file).

Is there an easy interface I override?  With the four layers (kotlin-logging, slf4j, slf4j-simple, Logger) I'm unsure where to start.  I thought it would be as easy as

```
someLoggingThing.addDestinationForSufficientlySevere(object:Logger { str->
   myAltLoggingThing.log(str)
})
```

Disclaimer: I don't know details logging practices and facades, which is why I liked the simplicity of kotlin-logging so much (the lambda handles the "don't do any thinking if debugging is turned off" issue)

```
private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}
logger.debug { "I'm a debug lumberjack and I'm ok $withComplicatedStuff" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to do so by implementing your own logger and bind it to slf4j. So it will replace the "simpld logging". If you want both in that logger you can call the simple logger. See the details here:
[Implement Custom Logger with slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653855/implement-custom-logger-with-slf4j)

Comment: Would be nice to have the answer post elaborate on how this is done. For instance:
- Is this suggesting not to use KotlinLogging?
- What does the custom logger look like, along with configuration in kotlin?
- How does this solve the problem specificially?