# java (log4j) logging filter by object type

Tags: java, logging, filter, log4j

I have a logging statement currently implemented with log4j:

```
log.info("Failed to create message for {}", CustomerData);
```

This will log some sensitive data in `CustomerData`.

Is there a way to block logging of any instances of `CustomerData`? Maybe in log4j configuration or via a custom filter?

If not possible with log4j, how about other logging frameworks?

Comment: Not clear what do you ask.

Comment: What does the `CustomerData.toString()` method look like?

Comment: @stdunbar CustomerData.toString will be logged. An example might be "Customer name: Jon Smith, Customer gender: male, Customer age: 25, Customer balance: $100". As you can see this contains sensitive data and I was wondering if there is any way to set a filter to block the possibility of logging any objects of type `CustomerData`.

Comment: @RomanC what clarification or what concrete doubt do you have? I thought it is a simple and straight forward question. I am asking on the possibility of excluding or blocking any objects of a certain type/class `CustomerData` and ways to do it if possible.

Comment: @Jesse It's unclear what do you asking. Because it's not possible to do it.

Comment: @RomanC I was asking the possibility to do it. I did not find a way to do it with log4j. Thanks for providing your opinion that it is not possible. But I thought it might be possible to somehow intercept and identify the object type so just want to ask this question in case anyone knows.

Comment: @JesseZhuang I believe there is a little confusion in this question. When you type log.info("abcdefgh {}", someStringHere) it will log the String "abcdefgh " + whatever the value of someStringHere is. So in your case, whatever CustomerData.toString()'s result is will be concatenated onto the end of the previous string before logging it. If you have sensitive data with CustomerData, why are you logging it?

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper the hope was to have some mechanism to prevent future developers on the team to log sensitive data accidentally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log4j2 offers a number of ways to accomplish this:

- **Filters**
- **Rewriting Log Events**

---

## Filters

Log4j2 allows you to configure [filters](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html) on specific loggers, or on specific appenders, or globally (so the filter applies to all log events). What filters give you is the ability to force-ACCEPT a log event, or force-DENY a log event, or to be "NEUTRAL". In your case you may want to DENY log events that contain sensitive data.

You can create a [custom Filter implementation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Filters) (see the [plugin docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html) for how to install your custom filter), or you can use some of the built-in filters. Either the built-in [RegexFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#RegexFilter) or a [ScriptFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#Script) should be sufficient for your purposes.

#### *Regex filter example*

Let's say that this is a class that contains sensitive data:

```
public class Customer {
    public String name;
    public String password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer[name=" + name + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }
}
```

And your application logging looks something like this:

```
public class CustomerLoggingApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.name = "Jesse Zhuang";
        customer.password = "secret123";

        log.info("This is sensitive and should not be logged: {}", customer);
        log.info("But this message should be logged.");
    }
}
```

You can configure a regex filter that looks at the formatted (or unformatted) message and DENY any log messages that have the word "`Customer`" followed by "`, password=`" in them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <RegexFilter regex=".*Customer.*, password=.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %level %c %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

#### *Script filter example*

Another very flexible filter is [ScriptFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#Script). The below example uses Groovy, but you can also use JavaScript or whatever other scripting language is available on your Java installation.

Given the above application classes, the following `log4j2.xml` configuration would filter out any log events containing any parameters whose fully qualified class name is `Customer`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
  <ScriptFilter onMatch="DENY" onMisMatch="NEUTRAL">
    <Script name="DropSensitiveObjects" language="groovy"><![CDATA[
                parameters.any { p ->
                    // DENY log messages with Customer parameters
                    p.class.name == "Customer"
                }
              ]]>
    </Script>
  </ScriptFilter>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %level %c %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

---

## Rewriting Log Events

Another interesting option is to rewrite the log event so that the message does not get completely filtered out, but instead you just mask the sensitive data. For example you replace the password string with "***" in the log.

To do this, you create a [RewriteAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RewriteAppender). From the manual:

> The RewriteAppender allows the LogEvent to manipulated before it is
>   processed by another Appender. This can be used to mask sensitive
>   information such as passwords or to inject information into each
>   event.

Example rewrite policy:

```
package com.jesse.zhuang;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Core;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rewrite.RewritePolicy;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginElement;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.Message;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ObjectMessage;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterizedMessage;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ReusableMessage;

@Plugin(name = "MaskSensitiveDataPolicy", category = Core.CATEGORY_NAME, 
        elementType = "rewritePolicy", printObject = true)
public class MaskSensitiveDataPolicy implements RewritePolicy {

    private String[] sensitiveClasses;

    @PluginFactory
    public static MaskSensitiveDataPolicy createPolicy(
            @PluginElement("sensitive") final String[] sensitiveClasses) {
        return new MaskSensitiveDataPolicy(sensitiveClasses);
    }

    private MaskSensitiveDataPolicy(String[] sensitiveClasses) {
        super();
        this.sensitiveClasses = sensitiveClasses;
    }

    @Override
    public LogEvent rewrite(LogEvent event) {
        Message rewritten = rewriteIfSensitive(event.getMessage());
        if (rewritten != event.getMessage()) {
            return new Log4jLogEvent.Builder(event).setMessage(rewritten).build();
        }
        return event;
    }

    private Message rewriteIfSensitive(Message message) {
        // Make sure to switch off garbage-free logging
        // by setting system property `log4j2.enable.threadlocals` to `false`.
        // Otherwise you may get ReusableObjectMessage, ReusableParameterizedMessage
        // or MutableLogEvent messages here which may not be rewritable...
        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            return rewriteObjectMessage((ObjectMessage) message);
        }
        if (message instanceof ParameterizedMessage) {
            return rewriteParameterizedMessage((ParameterizedMessage) message);
        }
        return message;
    }

    private Message rewriteObjectMessage(ObjectMessage message) {
        if (isSensitive(message.getParameter())) {
            return new ObjectMessage(maskSensitive(message.getParameter()));
        }
        return message;
    }

    private Message rewriteParameterizedMessage(ParameterizedMessage message) {
        Object[] params = message.getParameters();
        boolean changed = rewriteSensitiveParameters(params);
        return changed ? new ParameterizedMessage(message.getFormat(), params) : message;
    }

    private boolean rewriteSensitiveParameters(Object[] params) {
        boolean changed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            if (isSensitive(params[i])) {
                params[i] = maskSensitive(params[i]);
                changed = true;
            }
        }
        return changed;
    }

    private boolean isSensitive(Object parameter) {
        return parameter instanceof Customer;
    }

    private Object maskSensitive(Object parameter) {
        Customer result = new Customer();
        result.name = ((Customer) parameter).name;
        result.password = "***";
        return result;
    }
}
```

> **CAUTION**: When running in garbage-free mode (the default), Log4j2 uses reusable objects for messages and log events. These are not
>   suitable for rewriting. (This is not documented well in the user
>   manual.) If you want to use the rewrite appender, **you need to
>   partially switch off garbage-free logging** by setting system property
>   `log4j2.enable.threadlocals` to `false`.

Configure your rewrite appender with your custom `MaskSensitiveDataPolicy` rewrite policy. To let Log4j2 know about your plugin, specify the name of the package of your plugin in the `packages` attribute of the `Configuration`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" packages="com.jesse.zhuang">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %level %c %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </Console>

    <Rewrite name="obfuscateSensitiveData">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <MaskSensitiveDataPolicy />
    </Rewrite>

  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="obfuscateSensitiveData"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This will make the above example program produce the following output. Note that the password is masked but other attributes of the sensitive object are preserved:

```
2018-01-09 22:18:30,561 INFO CustomerLoggingApp This is sensitive and should not be logged: Customer[name=Jesse Zhuang, password=***]
2018-01-09 22:18:30,569 INFO CustomerLoggingApp But this message should be logged.
```

Comment: Just wonder, a quick glance on Log4j2 code, seems message formatting has already completed when constructing the logEvent in Logger,  so the logEvent reaching the appender should already be final message? I guess I may have missed something in the logger logic

Comment: In garbage free mode (the default), this may be the case yes. You may need to partially switch off garbage free logging by setting system property `log4j2.enable.threadlocals` to false.

Answer (score 2):

It is not (and probably will never be) provided in Log4j/SLF4j/whatever Logging framework.

In order to cope with your specific need, the easiest way is to have your own decorator of Logger.

It can be a custom logging implementation for SLF4J or Log4j2.  Or simply some kind of factory for `Logger` (i.e. like LoggerFactory in SLF4j, or `Logger.getLogger()` for Log4j2)

It could internally create your custom Logger implementation, which delegates to the real logger, and you do extra checking in your logging impl.

e.g. (psuedo-code)

```
SensitiveDataCheckingLogger implements Logger {
    private Logger delegate;
    public SensitiveDataCheckingLogger(Logger delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void info (String message, Object... args) {
        if (delegate.infoEnabled()) {
            for (Object arg : args) {
                // or whatever way you want to check, e.g. by annotation 
                if (arg instanceof SenstiveData) {  
                    throw newOhNoSensitiveDataRuntimeException();
                }
            }

            delegate.info(message, args);
        }
    }
    // bunch of all other method implementations
}

public class MyLoggerFactory {
    Logger getLogger(Class<?> clazz) {
        return new SensitiveDataCheckingLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz));
    }
}
```

so you just use it in similar way as before

```
Logger logger = MyLoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);
...
logger.info("bablabla {}", sensitiveData);
```

---

But as you can see, there are a lot of drawbacks, like performance degrade.

---

If you are using Logback (I believe you can do similar for Log4j2 too), you may implement your own Appender, or Encoder etc.

When you log in Logback, it internally creates a log event, which contains the log message plus the parameters.  So instead of actually formatting the log message in your appender (or encoder etc), you just do the parameters checking and throw exception if it does not look right.

Caution for this approach:
- Appender is only reached if log level is enabled.  Therefore if in config you set log level to WARN, then you won't be able to catch log message done by `logger.info("message {}", senstive);`
- it has more to do with the internal implementation for the logging implementation you are using, which means it is harder to switch to other implementation (which is rare in real life I believe)

The advantage is, if you don't already have your own logging API, it helps to save code change as you can stick to SLF4J / Log4j2 APIs

---

Edit:

Just checked in Log4j2, it allow you to replace the MessageFactory (which is used to construct the message string based on message + params).

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html

> ### MessageFactory
>
> A MessageFactory is used to generate Message objects.
>   Applications may replace the standard ParameterizedMessageFactory (or
>   ReusableMessageFactory in garbage-free mode) by setting the value of
>   the system property log4j2.messageFactory to the name of the custom
>   MessageFactory class.
>
> Flow messages for the Logger.entry() and Logger.exit() methods have a
>   separate FlowMessageFactory. Applications may replace the
>   DefaultFlowMessageFactory by setting the value of the system property
>   log4j2.flowMessageFactory to the name of the custom FlowMessageFactory
>   class.

So, similar to above method, you can create your own `MessageFactory` which do extra param checking

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to prevent this is to write/overwrite your `CustomerData.toString()` method.

Other than that you can extend slf4j but don't ask me how to do that.

[Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1770588/4727762)